# Multiple fetch calls using fetchMock & `userEvent.click` within a `test.each` using React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm looking to test a number of outcomes given the respons of a callback to an endpoit we are making requests to.

Given the code below:

```js
describe('when I click the "continue to shop" button', () => {
test.only.each`
    applicationStatus                     | routeName                   | routeURL
    ${'CASH_ACCEPT'}                      | ${'Checkout Shipping'}      | ${'/checkout/shipping.page'}
    ${'DECLINED'}                         | ${'Account Rejected'}       | ${'/account/application/accountRejected.page'}
    ${'EXISTING_ACCOUNT_PROFILE_MATCHED'} | ${'Existing Account Found'} | ${'/account/accountFound.page?email=c***********4@example.com'}
    ${'a non-recognised'}                 | ${'Server Error'}           | ${'/serverError.page'}
`(
    'then the $applicationStatus response should take me to the $routeName page',
    async ({ applicationStatus, routeURL }) => {
        fetchMock.post(`/api/account-application/applications`, {
            data: {
                id: '123',
                type: 'account-application',
                attributes: {
                    applicationStatus: `${applicationStatus}`,
                    email: 't*********@example.com',
                },
            },
        });

        const component = render(<Benefits experiments={experiments} />);

        await act(async () => {
            await userEvent.click(component.getByText(/Continue to shop/i));
        });

        expect(component.getByTestId('loading-overlay'));

        // eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename
        expect(global.open).toBeCalledWith(`${routeURL}`, '_self');
    },
);
```

I would expect each test iteration to be fired only once However, it seems that each test is faliing. It seems that the `userEvent.click` is happening more than once and is saving the previous click:

```js
Expected: "/account/accountFound.page?email=c_**\***_4@example.com", "\_self"
Received
1: "/checkout/shipping.page", "\_self"
2: "/account/application/accountRejected.page", "\_self"
3: "/account/accountFound.page?email=t**\***@example.com", "\_self"

Number of calls: 3
```

My understanding is that after each test,`cleanup` is ran and eveything should be reset before the next. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `expect(global.open)` assertion that fails, not `userEvent.click`.

Jest doesn't reset spy calls by default, and no manual cleanup is performed in provided code.

Use `resetAllMocks` or `restoreAllMocks`:

```
afterEach(() => {
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
});
```

The latter requires to set up `global.open` spy before each test and not only once.

Or better, enable [`resetMocks`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#resetmocks-boolean) or [`restoreMocks`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#restoremocks-boolean) configuration option, because cross-contamination is almost never desirable in well-written tests.